# Check if my array follows a specific format

Tags: python, arrays, string, loops

I am trying to figure out a way in python using a loop to check if my array follows the format

```
[string,number,symbol,string,number,symbol.......]
```

What would be the easiest way to do this?

Comment: Use an `assert ()`, it will give you an assertion error if its not in the correct format.

Comment: What is symbol? can you give a simple example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write simple function where you match your "type" with corresponding validator and then use `all()` to check is each element of given array match format:

```
def validate(array, format):
    if len(array) != len(format):
        return False

    validators = {
        'string': lambda s: isinstance(s, str),
        'number': lambda i: isinstance(i, (int, float)),
        'symbol': lambda c: isinstance(c, str) and len(c) == 1,
        'bool': lambda x: isinstance(x, bool)
    }

    return all(validators.get(fmt, lambda _: False)(el) for el, fmt in zip(array, format))

array_sample = ['aaa', 0, 'b', 10.0, False]
format_sample = ['string', 'number', 'symbol', 'number', 'bool']

result = validate(array_sample, format_sample)
```

You can use regular for loop instead of `all()` if it's strict requirement:

```
...
for el, fmt in zip(array, format):
    if not (fmt in validators and validators[fmt](el)):
        return False

return True
```